# Logstash output Performance

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, bigdata

I 'am using Elasticsearch 5.1.1 , logstash 5.1.1 ,I imported 3 millions rows from sqlserver into elastic via logstash in **2 hours**

I have 1 single windows machine with 4GB Ram , core I 3  ): is there any additional configurations should I add to speed up the importing ?

I tried to change logstash.yml settings  via https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html

but it doesn't affect

**Logstash Configurations**

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "D:\Usefull_Jars\sqljdbc4-4.0.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.5.14:1433;databaseName=DataSource;integratedSecurity=false;user=****;password=****;"
jdbc_user => "****"
jdbc_password => "****"
statement => "SELECT * FROM RawData"
jdbc_fetch_size => 1000
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "localhost"
index => "testdata"
document_type => "testfeed"
document_id => "%{id}"
flush_size => 512
}
}
```

**logstash.yml**

```
pipeline:
     batch:
       size: 125
       delay: 2
 #
 # Or as flat keys:
 #   pipeline.batch.size: 125
 #   pipeline.batch.delay: 5
 # ------------ Pipeline Settings --------------
 # Set the number of workers that will, in parallel, execute the filters+outputs
 # stage of the pipeline.
 # This defaults to the number of the host's CPU cores.
 pipeline.workers: 5
 # How many workers should be used per output plugin instance
 pipeline.output.workers: 5
 # How many events to retrieve from inputs before sending to filters+workers
 pipeline.batch.size: 125
 # How long to wait before dispatching an undersized batch to filters+workers
 # Value is in milliseconds.
 # pipeline.batch.delay: 5
 # ------------ Queuing Settings --------------
 #
 # Internal queuing model, "memory" for legacy in-memory based queuing and
 # "persisted" for disk-based acked queueing. Defaults is memory
 #
 # queue.type: memory
 #
 # If using queue.type: persisted, the directory path where the data files will be stored.
 # Default is path.data/queue
 #
 # path.queue:
 #
 # If using queue.type: persisted, the page data files size. The queue data consists of
 # append-only data files separated into pages. Default is 250mb
 #
 # queue.page_capacity: 250mb
 #
 # If using queue.type: persisted, the maximum number of unread events in the queue.
 # Default is 0 (unlimited)
 #
 # queue.max_events: 0
 #
 # If using queue.type: persisted, the total capacity of the queue in number of bytes.
 # If you would like more unacked events to be buffered in Logstash, you can increase the 
 # capacity using this setting. Please make sure your disk drive has capacity greater than 
 # the size specified here. If both max_bytes and max_events are specified, Logstash will pick 
 # whichever criteria is reached first
 # Default is 1024mb or 1gb
 #
 # queue.max_bytes: 1024mb
 #
 # If using queue.type: persisted, the maximum number of acked events before forcing a checkpoint
 # Default is 1024, 0 for unlimited
 #
 # queue.checkpoint.acks: 1024
 #
 # If using queue.type: persisted, the maximum number of written events before forcing a checkpoint
 # Default is 1024, 0 for unlimited
 #
 # queue.checkpoint.writes: 1024
 #
 # If using queue.type: persisted, the interval in milliseconds when a checkpoint is forced on the head page
 # Default is 1000, 0 for no periodic checkpoint.
 #
 # queue.checkpoint.interval: 1000
```

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: How many worker threads running for logstash??

Comment: pipeline.workers: 5 in logstash.yml

Comment: could you post the logstash.yml?

Comment: i have some suggestion. decrease jdbc_fetch_size => 300 and pipeline.workers: 8 and pipeline.output.workers: 8 and increase memory of logstash with 2 GB

Comment: while indexing put a top command and post the output..

Comment: @BlackPOP please where to configure memory

Comment: Set memory in conf folder jvm.options file and replace-Xms256m
-Xmx1g with  -Xms512m -Xmx2g